# Checkboxes disappearing when uploading to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I have written a controller to take input from the form containing a list of options. The options have to be selected using checkboxes. I have successfully tested the code on my local machine. But when uploaded to the app engine, the webpage is not displaying the checkbox fields. It is not displaying the options either. I tested with 3 browsers - IE, Mozilla and Chrome and this happens everywhere. But, everything is working on fine on the browsers when running on local machine. I am quite confused as to what is going wrong. 
Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to setup [static file/directory](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers) mappings in app.yaml.

You need to provide us with more details to help you debug issues.  For example, if the browser doesn't display what you expect tell us what it *does* display.  What happens if you view source?  Is your HTML there?